# R: how to reshape a data frame by column

Tags: r, merge, reshape

I have this initial data frame:

```
Date.Flight.Time    oil.Pressure    Date.Flight.Time.2  oil.temperature
20/06/2016 13.40    1               20/06/2016 13.40    10
20/06/2016 13.41    2               20/06/2016 13.41    20
21/06/2016 13.42    3               21/06/2016 13.42    30
22/06/2016 13.43    4               28/06/2016 13.46    40
27/06/2016 13.44    5               30/06/2016 13.47    50
27/06/2016 13.45    6               NA
28/06/2016 13.46    7               NA
30/06/2016 13.47    8               NA
```

and I want this final data frame:

```
Date.Flight.Time    oil.Pressure    Date.Flight.Time.1  oil.temperature
20/06/2016 13.40    1               20/06/2016 13.40    10
20/06/2016 13.41    2               20/06/2016 13.41    20
21/06/2016 13.42    3               21/06/2016 13.42    30
22/06/2016 13.46    7               28/06/2016 13.46    40
27/06/2016 13.47    8               30/06/2016 13.47    50
```

how to attain it?

So, I want time and date in the same row. 
Exemple: in the first data frame I have in row Number four different time and date in the same row. I would like coincidence.

Comment: based on ? I mean what are the criteria you are rejecting the above rows?

Comment: @YCR *do no HARM/SPAM* `s the word/phrase

Comment: The names of the data frame must be unique.. `Date Flight Time` appears twice...

Answer (score 2):

You can merge the 2 parts of your data.frame by date of flight:

```
mydf2 <- merge(mydf[, 1:2], mydf[, 3:4], by.x="Date.Flight.Time", by.y="Date.Flight.Time.2")
mydf2
#  Date.Flight.Time oil.Pressure oil.temperature
#1 20/06/2016 13.40            1              10
#2 20/06/2016 13.41            2              20
#3 21/06/2016 13.42            3              30
#4 28/06/2016 13.46            7              40
#5 30/06/2016 13.47            8              50
```

Answer (score -1):

The right statement is:

```
your.data.frame <- na.omit(your.data.frame)
```

Comment: No, it is not. With your solution you just omit NA value, but don't reshape by Data Flight Time.